# Streaming .m3u file in Android 3.0

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am looking to develop an application where I have to stream .m3u file, this is for ANDROID 3.0 only.

I want to stream this link 
dl.dropbox.com/u/2377944/test/abr_test/index.m3u8
it must work in emulator too

I searched a lot, but nothing seems to be working too good.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: m3u is a playlist format, are you sure you want to stream that and not the music files?

Comment: Show us what you have and ask specific questions so that we can give you help.

Comment: @Piskvor: yeah, I have to stream .m3u file.

Answer (score 0):

m3u is a play list format, a text file, and not actually audio/video media itself.  That means it references media that you would want to stream.  The distinction is important.

The contents of the m3u file is important.  (Your link is dead, btw.)  Show that to use and we can help more.  Each of the media files contained in the m3u must be valid and point to media that is compatible with Android.

What makes the media compatable?  Check the [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) page.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, here is the link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2377944/test/abr_test/index.m3u8
the m3u8 file is an index to .ts files (which are segments of mpeg2). 
The m3u8 file only work on the iPhone n iPOd touch, working on Vplayer for Andorid too. But I need to stream this file in to my application. And I am getting no clue regarding that.

Comment: Edited link in my question too !